# How to fix output to be on separate lines to create a 5x5 matrix?

Tags: java, matrix, printing

Creating a 5x5 matrix with random double numbers. The ouput is correct however it is all on one line. How can I avoid this?

I have tried adding ln at the end of System.out.print but I get the same result.

```
    private static double[][] RandomArray(int n) {
    double[][] randomMatrix = new double [n][n];
    double[] randomArray = new double [n];
     Random rand = new Random(); 
        rand.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis()); 

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {   

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            Integer r = rand.nextInt()% 100; 
            randomMatrix[i][j] = Math.abs(r);
        }

    }

    return randomMatrix;
}


public static void main(String[] args){

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(RandomArray(5)));
}
 }
```

[[96.0, 11.0, 9.0, 69.0, 10.0], [76.0, 96.0, 51.0, 86.0, 11.0], [74.0, 67.0, 73.0, 99.0, 32.0], [51.0, 90.0, 86.0, 84.0, 85.0], [69.0, 30.0, 21.0, 36.0, 89.0]]
I expect the output to be arrays on seperate individual lines so it looks almost like a 5x5 box. The output is one long line with all the arrays, but that is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you need to format your array so that when it prints to the console you have the information in the desired order. The `Arrays.deepToString(RandomArray(5))` simply takes in an array and converts it to a string. The way the method handles 2D arrays is to use brackets to wrap each row and then wrap all the rows with a larger bracket, which is then your matrix.
If you want code in your console to look like a matrix, you have to print it out like so. Using a nested for loop (which is a for loop inside a for loop), you can print the data out in a way that looks more "grid-like."
A possible solution to your issue could look something like this:

```
double[][] matrix = RandomArray(5);
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Alternatively if you want to keep the brackets on the end of each row and use the `Arrays.deepToString()` method, you could do something like:

```
double[][] matrix = RandomArray(5);
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix[i]));
}
```

It is helpful to think of a matrix as just an array of arrays, so if you wanted a whole row, you could simply just take `randomMatrix[0]` and you would be looking at the first 5 long array that you created.